# Error Android SqlCipher

Tags: android, sql, cryptoapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При сборке Android-sqlcipher возникает вот такая ошибка, как ее убрать?

Answer (score 0):

Это означает что отсутствует tool chain для архитектуры Intel x86

Если быть совсем точным означает, что у вас не установлен [Android Native Development Kit](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)

Comment: перепроверил путь, правда был не тот теперь вот такая ошибка возникает, может быть что-нибудь известно?